# Learning IN values

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a IN values statement. This is my query:

I did `mysql_escape_string` on each of the elements in the `IN` so `mysql_escape_string('http://www.blah.com/%s')` gave me `http://www.blah.com/%s`

```
SELECT * FROM social_handlers WHERE (`group` = 0 OR `url_template` IN ("http://www.blah.com/%s", "totally bogus val")) AND update_time > 0
```

It keeps telling me this error though:

> MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`url_template` IN ("http://www.blah.com/%s", "totally bogus val")) AND update_ti' at line 1

How can I identify this error?

This is my social_handlers table:

[image]

I also had to do `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connectid);` because i support Russian and Chinese characters.

Comment: could you please desc social_handlers; ?

Comment: Thanks @bourax i udated the topic

Comment: Your query seems to be fine and simple !

Comment: Thanks @bourax I'm so confused I thought so too it just keeps throwing this :( Do i have to escape that `%`?

Comment: I think about it too, usually I use it with LIKE , try without %s

Comment: I put a `\` before the `%` and it worked, so weird, how come `mysql_escape_string` wouldnt do anything on it? :(